# Issue with laptop touchscreen

Tags: kernel, touchscreen, 16.04

I have 16:04 installed in laptop. Touchscreen of my laptop doesn't work with this distribution. With 14.04 ,it was working, even with 15.10 it worked. But with 16.04 it doesn't work. In my WIndows 10 partition it works fine. So I logged a bug request and team ubuntu told me

"try bisecting with mainline kernel builds, 15.04 had 3.19 so it
regressed between it and 4.4."

I don't know how to do that. Can anyone tell me how to perform and report it back to them so that my problem get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a mainline kernel you must go to the Ubuntu Kernel Mainline website and manually download and install 3 kernel packages:

1. The kernel **image** for your architecture
2. The kernel **headers** for your archiecture
3. The kernel **headers** for **all** archectures

Then you can install them with `dpkg -i` and reboot.  It should now appear as an option in your grub menu for you to try.

The process overall is outlined here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

and the Mainline Build Packages are available here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

As for reporting back, you need to open a bug on launchpad and add the kernel-bug-exists-upstream and kernel-bug-exists-upstream-X.Y.Z tags to the bug report.

Good luck!

Comment: I did it successfully and reported back. Thanks man !